# Gradle multi module - Spring app as a normal jar for the common module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Gradle multi module project and have a common module for invoking 3rd party service.
Using Webclient in the common module and hence included starter in the webflux.

> implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

Since I have included spring-boot-starter-webflux, it is trying to build as a bootJar and expecting the main application. It builds fine if I incldue a main application. But, this is just a common module and I would like to build this as a jar to be included in the main module.

Tried jar in the gradle and still it is not working. Is there any other way?

```
jar {
  enabled = true
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the whole gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-and-normal) in the spring documentation says how to do it.

And I tried this in one of my pet project. I was able to get a library (132k) instead of a spring boot app jar (50m)

```
bootJar {
  enabled = false
}

jar {
  enabled = true
}
```